# Spring Boot 2.2.5 get post request parameters

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, http

Is there a way to get request body(JSON) parameters without using a POJO object for each request?
I have two types of requests, in many of these request what I want is get a parameter from request,
for example something like this:

```
{"name": "Mike", "Age":25}
```

```java
request.getBodyParameter("name");
```

and for some of my requests I want to convert the input json to a JAVA hash map.

Comment: That isn't a request parameter but a JSON body. So no you cannot do that, you need to convert it to either an object or a map and get it from there.

Comment: so for each post request in my project which contains json as it's body, I need to create a POJO for transfering data ?

Comment: That or create a map which holds the structure.

Comment: I'm new to spring can you give me a link or example ?

Comment: @mhndev I have updated the answer with the lib u have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public Status getJsonData(@RequestBody JsonObject jsonData){
}
```

from `jsonData` 
yo can do `jsonData.getString("name")` or you can convert this into map

```
HashMap<String,Object> result =
        new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonData, HashMap.class);
```

***Update***

```
 public Status getJsonData(@RequestBody JsonNode jsonNode){
   String name = jsonNode.get("name").asText();
}
```

For conversion to map

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> result = mapper.convertValue(jsonNode, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});
```

Comment: I'm using Jackson for Json in my project, which I think is default Json Lib in Spring boot,
and I don't have JsonObject class in my project.
can you suggest an other solution using Jackson ?

Comment: try JsonNode class

Answer (score 1):

Use `JsonNode` to take dynamic object;

Here is example

```
   @PostMapping("/mapping")
    public String getDynamicData(@RequestBody JsonNode jsonNode) {
        String name = jsonNode.get("name").asText();
        return name;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert JSON into hashmap in `controller` than below solution will work. `ObjectConvetore reduce your performance. It's an extra conversion`.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
@RequestMapping(value = "/hi", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public void startMartExecution(@RequestBody(required = true) Map<String,String> martCriterias) {
        System.out.println(martCriterias.get("name"));
}
```

If you call `restAPI from your application` thn below code will work.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.ALL));
HttpEntity<Void> entity = new HttpEntity<Void>(null, headers);
Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();
ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>> parameterizedTypeReference = new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {};
ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> result = restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, entity, parameterizedTypeReference);
body = result.getBody();
```

Thank You

Comment: Thanks Birju, now I have the hash map.

Comment: You should use hashmap in requestbody itself because it jackson support this casting and it improve your performance in time and size both.

Comment: can I use @requestBody multiple times in my method arguments ?

Comment: No, But do you want to do that?

Comment: I wanted to have the request both as my entity and also as Json Object

Comment: You can take as a HashMap and whenever you need a pojo object , you can convert into entity